# How to wire pull-down/up on an N- or P-channel MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet

I'm switching a 24 V signal and using a MOSFET as a relay and a 5 V signal to the gate.

How and where should I place a pull-up or pull-down resistor on the drain or source to ensure a stable reference in case the MOSFET is open, ie. if my MOSFET drives a PLC I/O?

Comment: p-mos or n-mos ?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use an N-channel MOSFET only and put the pullup (if you need one) between drain and +24. This is equivalent to an "NPN output" aka "sinking" in industrial control terminology.

In that case the PLC input will typically be "current sourcing" and you will not need a pullup resistor. Image from [this](https://library.automationdirect.com/3-wire-sinking-sourcing-devices-plc-input-modules/) web page.

If you do add a pullup (and if it is low enough value) it may be able to drive a PLC current sinking input.

[image]

Driving a P-channel from a 5V signal (sourcing or PNP output) is a bit more complex and requires level shifting if the 0V/5V ground is not common with the +24V ground.

Comment: Pull up and pull down used to guarantee off are from the Source to Gate.

Comment: @gil he's using the term "unconventionally" but not wrongly.